# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Razor Form Validate Required Field

Tags: textbox, required

Hi I have  Razor View that Generate a list of Addresses. 
among all address the Phone Number Text Box is set as Required using MVC Data annotations. 
But I have a Problem.
Let say If my form is Rendering 3 Addresses for a particular Customer. 
and customer is suppose to enter Three Phone Numbers. 
If a customer doesn't enter number in any three text boxes, then all the text boxes will have validation messages saying Required.
But If Customer enter a Phone Number in the First Text Box 
Then All the text boxes are considered as validated and accepting the submit button.
how can i fix this, so that the Required validation should work per individual Text Box.

Comment: Sounds like a model problem with your view. Can you post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed. what i did is

```
@html.Textboxfor(x=>x.Phone)
```

was generating common html name tag for all the Phone numbers in the list.
and this was creating problem. 
so what I did was instead of Html helpers,
I wrote a standard input Tag

```
<input type= "text" value="@html.displayfor(x=>x.phone)" name="Phone @html(x=>x.phone)" />
```

and then used jQuery to Validate the Text box format and make it Required on change event.

Any ways thanks for your time.